# Winform Application Configuration on Install

Tags: .net

This question is related to Winform application deployment and configuration.

I am new to .net development and I am working on my first Winforms application. Whenever I deploy the application I need to set the value of the server to which the user will be connecting.

For this I have to go into program files and change the application configuration file manually using Notepad.

Not only have I heard that this is not a good practice, it is also a tedious exercise. Imagine going to half a dozen users and doing the same thing on each machine.

I am very confused as to what to do. The application config file that is in the same folder as the exe is the file thorugh which I can change the connection string (as I am given to understand).

Can anyone help me to solve the following questions.

1. How do I update the application configuration file after I install it without having to open it up in Notepad? My main concern is updating the connection string.
2. I have heard that using the registry is a possibility in this case. I am scared of using the registry! Is this an option?

Please excuse my ignorance if the questions are naive. I am new to .net and looking for answers

Thanks
Romi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Romi here is a code snippet that can help you in read/right application configurations

for write in the

```
     System.Configuration.Configuration config =
     ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
                (ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Add an Application Setting.

    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ModificationDate",
                   DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " ");

    // Save the changes in App.config file.

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    // Force a reload of a changed section.

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

to read

```
    foreach(string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
    {
       string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
       Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, value);
    }
```

my advice: if your are saving several settings that are not connection strings use the above code. just create a simple form, create a dictionary fill it and show it using a grid control.

if you only  need to read/write connection strings use the following code

to read

```
  string cnx =      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

to write

```
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString=" your conenction string here";
```

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

```
    // Force a reload of a changed section.

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("ConnectionString");
```

you can still use the registry to save those settings but I belive the code above will solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I can create a form either as a part of the main application or as a form that is brought up post deployment that accepts a server name, connects to the same and if connection is successful then save it to the config file using the code you have provided. That would be the idea? right?

Comment: sure why not, there are a lot of things you can do with the code, its really useful. You can even save several connection strings just replacing the name withing the quotes in the following line:ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["replace this"].ConnectionString=" your conenction string here";